# How variables are accessed in C#/Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just starting to learn Unity/C#.

One thing I am confused about in the C# scripts is that variables from classes are used, but the classes arn't directly accessed?

For example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){
        Destroy(gameObject);;
    }
}
```

How is `gameObject` accessed if the class isn't accessed? For example, how is it not:

`Destroy(UnityEngine.gameObject)` (or something similar)?

I also cannot see the lowercase `gameObject` on the [documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).

Comment: [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html)

Comment: According to the documentation it seem to be a property of the extended [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong documentation. The word `gameObject` here refers to a property of the class `Test`, that is *inherited* from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html), which is in turn inherited from [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html), which is in turn inherited from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html).

Notice the inheritance clause in the declaration of `Test`:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's what causes `Test` to gain the `gameObject` property.

Because `gameObject` is a member of `Test`, you do not need to qualify it when you access it. You can just say "`gameObject`", in the same way that you do not need to prefix the access to `foo` here:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    int foo = 10;
    void Start(){
        Debug.Log(foo); // you don't need to write anything before "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that explains it mostly. However in your example, `foo` is explicitly initialised/stated, whereas in my question `gameObject` is not.

Comment: @Zorgan That is the point I am trying to make - *because* `gameObject` is inherited, you can access it *as if* it were explicitly "stated" (the proper word for this is "declared").

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. Does this also mean there are 1000s of variable names you can't use because `UnityEngine` would inherit so many?

Answer (score 2):

As various commenters are trying to say; it is part of the `MonoBehaviour` class, which is accessible for within the `Start` function, because your `Test` class inherits everything `MonoBehaviour` has.

See this documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Other available properties are:

- runInEditMode
- useGUILayout
- enabled
- isActiveAndEnabled
- gameObject
- tag
- transform
- hideFlags
- name